# Boost regular expression for match whole word does not work

Tags: c++, boost

I am using some regular expression with boost to search for whole word inside some string.
The source looks like this:

```
boost::regex  regExp;
std::string searchExpression;

searchExpression = "((\\b)" + searchExpression + "(\\b)|(?<=^|\\s)" + searchExpression + "(?=\\s|$))";
regExp.assign(lConvertedSearchExpression, boost::regex_constants::normal | boost::regex_constants::icase);
```

The regular expression inside `searchExpression` is working well on my other tools. So I think there will be nothing wrong.
But if I try to assign the string to `boost::regex` as you can see in the example I got an exception. The exception is from the part `"(?<=^|\\s)"`. If I remove the part `"|\\s"` everything is working well.

So my question is now what I am doing wrong inside these expression. I hope there is someone can help me and does see the mistake.

Special Thanks to all which can help me in forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [boost::regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.lookbehind) documentation states that a lookbehind needs to be a fixed length. Your lookbehind matches zero or one character.

Comment: Thanks. This was the right solution for me. I doesn´t know this constellation before.

Comment: Oof. I would never have known. This is good content for [SO]